# Calculate Interest For Mint Token

Tags: token, solidity

I saw this code but I didn't understand how he calculated the interest rate . this contract mint tokens as an interest and transfer them to users who deposited to the contract (calculated according to the Hold time)  I will be grateful if anyone can help ?
https://github.com/dappuniversity/dbank/blob/master/src/contracts/dBank.sol

```
//check user's hodl time
uint depositTime = block.timestamp - depositStart[msg.sender];


**//31668017 - interest(10% APY) per second for min. deposit amount (0.01 ETH), cuz:
//1e15(10% of 0.01 ETH) / 31577600 (seconds in 365.25 days)
//(etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] / 1e16) - calc. how much higher interest will be (based on deposit), e.g.:
//for min. deposit (0.01 ETH), (etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] / 1e16) = 1 (the same, 31668017/s)
//for deposit 0.02 ETH, (etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] / 1e16) = 2 (doubled, (2*31668017)/s)
uint interestPerSecond = 31668017 * (etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] / 1e16);
uint interest = interestPerSecond * depositTime;**


//send funds to user
msg.sender.transfer(etherBalanceOf[msg.sender]); //eth back to user
token.mint(msg.sender, interest); //interest to user
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `depositTime` is the number of seconds from the last deposit.
2. `interestPerSecond` is calculated from the current ETH balance of the user deposited to the contract
3. And the `interest` amount is a simple multiplication between the two above.

---

Example:

The user has deposited 1 ETH exactly 30 days ago (2,592,000 seconds). This makes the

1. `depositTime` == **2592000**
2. `interestPerSecond` == 31668017 * (etherBalanceOf[msg.sender] / 1e16) == 31668017 * (1000000000000000000 / 1e16) == 31668017 * 100 == **3166801700**
3. `interest` == interestPerSecond * depositTime == 2592000 * 3166801700 == **8208350006400000**

Now, the linked contract imports another contract - [Token.sol](https://github.com/dappuniversity/dbank/blob/master/src/contracts/Token.sol), that imports the OpenZeppelin [ERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol).

The imported `ERC20.sol` defines 18 decimal places. So you need to account for 18 decimals to get the total amount of tokens that you get as the interest.

```
8208350006400000 / 1e18 == 0.00820835
```

So if you deposit 1 ETH 30 days ago, you get **0.00820835** of the token as an interest.